# Java. IO. Проблемы с чтением resources через относительный путь

Tags: java, resources, io

Падает с `NPE` в блоке try на строчке `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));`

```
private void getFileWithUtil() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try (InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/answer.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        this.fileContent = br.readLine();
        while (this.fileContent != null) {
            this.fileContent = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Файл лежит `src/main/resources/answer.txt` помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Во-первых, если путь начинается с символа `/`, то путь абсолютный и поиск происходит от корня каждого элемента classpath. Что у вас в classpath? Во-вторых, понятно где лежит файл, а в каком пакете находится код? Потому что относительный путь относителен корня пакета. Наконец, класс упакован в jar или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот таким образом, может кому-то будет полезно.

```
    private void writeFile() {
        try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(Constants.FILEPATH.getValue());
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
            String sub;
            while ((sub = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.fileContent = String.format("%s%s\n", this.fileContent, sub);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`FILEPATH.getValue()` равна `"/answer.txt"`

```
this.fileContent просто строка на полях
```